# Opening ENVI files in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, ndvi, envi, geotiff-tiff

I have calculated NDVI (vegetation index) in ENVI 5.2 and I saved it in TIFF format. Now I am trying to open it in ArcMap, but its not opening properly. The image is total black and the values are showing from 9 to -999.

How do I open the NDVI file properly in ArcMap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Have you tried calculating statistics? (Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Properties)

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/ndvi-function.htm

Perhaps this is a good place to start?

Comment: Yeah i did that. But the same result, a total black image